# Pyserial runtime error with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, cx-freeze, pyserial

I am trying to make an executable using cx_Freeze on a Raspberry Pi 3. The code all compiles without issue, but i get a runtime error:

```
  import serial
File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/__init__.py, line 12 in <module> standard_library.install_aliases()
File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/future/standard_library/__init__.py", line 487, in install_aliases
  from future.moves.test import support
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/test/test_support.py", line 642, in <module>
  character.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())\
TypeError: encode() argument 1 must be string, not None
```

The code works fine when run from the source. The error only shows when running the compiled version.

Anyone got any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` returning `None` as described here:

https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/323

I tried the suggested rollback to versions 5.0.2, 5.0.1, 5.0 but these just threw up different problems.

I have managed to hack this by altering the code on line 642 of `/usr/lib/python2.7/test/test_support.py` to a hard coded string `character.encode('UTF-8').decode('UTF-8')`

Although I now have this working, it would be nice to have a proper solution if anyone has one?